# dropzone.js & jquery: queuecomplete not working as expected

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js

here's my code:

```
$("div.tdropzone").dropzone({
    url: '/upload.php',

    error: function(file,message){
        this.removeFile(file);
        alert(message);
    },

    queuecomplete: function(){
        alert("Upload complete!");
    }

});
```

it's working as expected when uploading files has finished - but the problem is that queuecomplete is also being triggered if an error occurs .. is this a known bug? i'm expecting queuecomplete to be fired only after succesful upload.

Comment: Might be.See this: https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/578/#issuecomment-52333839

Comment: You should use dropzone events instead, like `success` or `successmultiple`, see http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-list